# How to receive/send files with a java Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, file

I'm writing a WebService in Java that should receive a file as an input, and then the WebService does some processing on that file, and finally it should send a new file to the client. How do I send a file to the client? (and how can I tell them to upload one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are generally transferred by encoding them with Base64 and putting them in `xsd:base64binary`

Comment: could You Please share any sample Project regarding this.?

Answer (score 1):

For large file, look for MTOM (Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism). From [JAX-WS Metro Guide: Binary attachment](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/Binary_Attachments__MTOM_.html):

> MTOM is efficient, in the sense that
>   it doesn't have the 33% size increase
>   penalty that `xs:base64Binary` has. It
>   is interoperable, in the sense that it
>   is a W3C standard. However, MIME
>   multipart incurs a small cost
>   proportional to the number of
>   attachments, so it is not suitable for
>   a large number of tiny attachments.